# How to properly create evenly spaced 2 column grid in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I don't know why I am having such a hard time with this, I have tried CSS Flex and FlatList.

I have a database table that looks like this:

id    title        pic
1     First        https://server.com/someimage.jpg
4     Another Pic  https://whatever.net/images/photo34834.png

I am trying to make a 2 column list that will be scrollable. It will have varying text lengths. So I will need to somehow determine the "safe" length of text I can use for the font size I use to make sure it does not break to a second line. I cannot, for the life of me, get these boxes to match up. Their widths won't match, and the font is also a problem. How is this properly done? (I have attached an image for reference of what I am trying to do)[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your images are not working, but if you want both containers to have the same width you can just assign the same width value percentage, like width: '45%'.